# drawing lines in tikz-timing

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-timing

I'm having some problems getting my node locations correct using tikz-timing.  I'd like the double-arrow line to be at the *center* of the pulse on both sides, instead of from bottom to top.  Also, I'd like to place the label "tw" below the center of that double arrow line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/slope=.005, yscale=2]
    Comparator Out & 2L  0.8H8.2L 0.8H 11.2L\\
    One-Shot Out & 2L N(A1)  4H N(A2) 5L4H 8L\\
    \extracode
    %\horlines[] {0,1,5}
    \tableheader[]{}{Case3: Two input pulses, far apart}
    \draw [<->] (A1.center) -- (A2.south);
    \node[] at (A1)  {tw};
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mS]

Comment: The `advnodes` tikz-timing library can be used here. It provides a `mid` anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some predefined anchors for a row in a `tikztimingtable`, see figure 2.1 in the `tikz-timing` manual. You can use one of the `mid` anchors of `row2` combined with the `(a |- b)` coordinate specification of TikZ, and thus draw the double arrow as

```
\draw [<->] (A1|-row2.mid) --node[below]{tw} (A2|-row2.mid);
```

The coordinate `(A1|-row2.mid)` is the point at the intersection of a vertical line through `A1` and a horizontal line through `row2.mid`, i.e. it has the x-coordinate of the former and the y-coordinate of the latter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/slope=.005, yscale=2]
    Comparator Out & 2L  0.8H8.2L 0.8H 11.2L\\
    One-Shot Out & 2L N(A1)  4H N(A2) 5L4H 8L\\
    \extracode
    %\horlines[] {0,1,5}
    \tableheader[]{}{Case3: Two input pulses, far apart}
    \draw [<->] (A1|-row2.mid) --node[below]{tw} (A2|-row2.mid);
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

## Old answer

I'm not that familiar with `tikz-timing`, so there might be better ways of doing it, but here is one using the `calc` library to calculate the midpoints of the vertical lines of the pulse.

To quickly explain what `($(A1|-A2)!0.5!(A1)$)` does. `($ ... $)` with the `calc` library loaded means that what is between the dollar signs is a calculation of sorts, as described in the manual.  `(A1|-A2)` is a coordinate specification, and it defines the coordinate that has the x-coordinate of `A1`, and the y-coordinate of `A2`, so the top left corner of the pulse. Finally the syntax `$(<first coord>)!<fraction>!(<second coord>)$` means that the result of the calculation is the coordinate that is `<fraction>` the way from the first to the second coordinate.

And to place a node below a line, place `node[below]{..}` right after a `--` in a path, as shown in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/slope=.005, yscale=2]
    Comparator Out & 2L  0.8H8.2L 0.8H 11.2L\\
    One-Shot Out & 2L N(A1)  4H N(A2) 5L4H 8L\\
    \extracode
    %\horlines[] {0,1,5}
    \tableheader[]{}{Case3: Two input pulses, far apart}
    \draw [<->] ($(A1|-A2)!0.5!(A1)$) -- node[below] {tw} ($(A2|-A1)!0.5!(A2)$);
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that `(A1|-A2)` syntax is nifty! You wouldn't by any chance be able to point me to where I could find some documentation on that? There's a lot of `|-` in the pgfman, but every instance of it which I've looked at so far seems to be talking about the path operation, not the coordinate magic you have going on here (I am presuming they are not the same?).

Comment: Thanks!  Your very patient description of the calc library syntax makes it very approachable.

Comment: @alpenwasser Section 13.3.1 *Intersections of perpendicular lines*. It's not the same as the path operation, no, though I suppose they're related. `\draw (a) |- (b);` would do the same as `\draw (a) -- (a|-b) -- (b);`

Comment: @ScottSeidman Looking quickly at the `tikz-timing` manual, there is a slightly easier method available as well, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  I was trying to use the .mid modifier on the nodes I created, with no love.  I find the docs for the package a hair to light on examples for a novice like me.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The nodes you've created have zero size, so it doesn't really matter if you use `A1.mid` or `A1.west` or some other anchor -- they're all at the same position. The `rowN` nodes on the other hand are defined automatically by the package, and encompass the entire signal on a specific row. So in figure 2.1 in the manual, replace `s` with e.g. `row2` to use an anchor on the second row of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how to place `tw` below the borderline for 0.2? Simply replacing `\draw [<->] (A1|-row2.mid) --node[below]{tw} (A2|-row2.mid);` with `\draw [<->] {(A1|-row2.end) + (0,-0.2)} --node[below]{tw} {(A2|-row2.end) + (0,-0.2)};` does not work.

Comment: @WDC Not at my computer now, so haven’t tested, but add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to the preamble, and try `($(A2|-row2.end) + (0, -0.2)$)`. It’s not enough to put braces around a coordinate calculation like you tried (where did you see that?).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks it works! I googled a link  (can't find it now) says that. Anyway highly appreciate your quick response.